# Use custom properties in the CSS with Polymer

Tags: css, polymer

I'm making a webapp using Polymer. I have a custom element that contains a paper-button. I have to set the ripple color of said button according to an attribute (or property?) so that in my main html file I can write
`<my-element ripplecolor="red"></my-element>`
I tried something like
`<paper-button style="--paper-button-ink-color: {{ripplecolor}};"></paper-button>`
but it doesnt work.

Comment: Could you also provide some relevant code?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that StackOverflow renders HTML. Fixed now.

Comment: Have a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omASiF85JzI) and this [link](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html) which will explain styling of Polymer elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

**In style:**

```
:host {    
  --my-ripple-color: red;
}
.someClass {
  --paper-button-ink-color: var(--my-ripple-color);
}
```

**In JS onload**

```
this.customStyle['--my-ripple-color'] = this.ripplecolor;
this.updateStyles();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Polymer 2 you have to use only [.updateStyles()](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#use-updatestyles-instead-of-customstyle)

```
style = this.getComputedStyleValue('--something');
```

And to get the style

```
if (window.ShadyCSS) {
  style = ShadyCSS.getComputedStyleValue(el, '--something');
} else {
  style = getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('--something');
}
```